# How to measure entire! LAN load for example with ntopng?

Tags: performance, lan

Is it possible to measure `LAN` load in the same way as it possible to measure `CPU` usage with `top`, i.e. in percent? For example, if I have 1 gigabit network, then how to know, how much of these bits are used?

`ntopng` shows a lot of beutiful plots which I don't understand. It is separate topic to learn them, currently I wonder, is it possible to see `LAN` load with it?

Comment: Which OS/platform? What kind of detail do you want (per process, per host, per interface...)?

Comment: @ZéLoff unix/linux platform; at least totals; may be per host; since you are asking "per interface" you probably assume the task is to monitor network usage of single computer; this is not the task; I need to measure load of entire `LAN`

Comment: This seems tough.  Your host (`A`) will only see multicast, broadcast, or src/dest traffic meant for `A`.  It cannot monitor traffic sent between `B` and `C` because the switch will not forward those packets to `A`.  You'd need to use functionality provided by the switch to monitor the entire LAN.  This is possible if you have a powerful switch. If you're more interested in traffic between your LAN and the outside world, then you could install your monitoring machine as a gateway.  Nagios is built for things like this.

Comment: @Stewart can't software put `NIC` into promiscuous mode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode#:~:text=In%20computer%20networking%2C%20promiscuous%20mode,that%20the%20controller%20is%20specifically

I was sniffing my network with `Wireshark` and it seemes to me that I saw packets between third party computers.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/):

> iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage. It listens to network traffic on a named interface and displays a table of current bandwidth usage by pairs of hosts. Handy for answering the question "why is our ADSL link so slow?".

The total transmit/receive values are shown at the bottom. The three columns show the 2, 10 and 40 second averages.

[image]

If you want to avoid lookups for the IP addresses use `sudo iftop -n`.

---

For monitoring the entire LAN, as you mentioned in your comment, you need to take a different approach. This depends on your network setup however.

For example if you have one router:

- check if your router can display statistics in the admin interface
- install a custom firmware, like DD-WRT, on your router if it supports this (for an example of how this would work see [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/222740/how-to-the-monitor-the-bandwidth-and-data-usage-of-individual-devices-on-your-network/))

Comment: Looks like this is about interactions of this very computer, not entire LAN?

Comment: Yes, monitoring the entire LAN is quite different. If that is what you are asking it is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You may be mixing up concepts.  You don't have a gigabit LAN, you have a network of gigabit *links* between nodes (and of course you can also have links of different speeds).  In this sense, you can only measure the bandwidth usage of each link, and the overall usage of the network will have to be some summary of this (mean, max, etc).

The only way to measure the usage of a given link is at one of its ends, so you'll probably want to do it at one of the networks hubs (I don't mean literally a hub device, but one of the nodes that is used to distribute packets), most likely a switch or a router.  How to do this depends greatly on your network infrastructure hardware.  You may have a gateway router `G` connected to a switch `S` to which nodes `A` and `B` are connected, and in this case you'd have to measure things at `S`, since traffic between `A` and `B` will be forwarded by the switch and won't reach the gateway.  Note that in many cases a router is actually a 2-port device with a switched attached to one of them.  If you add wifi into the equation then it becomes trickier, as the access point might forward packets between wifi hosts, so that would have to be measured on the AP on on the wifi clients.

If your switch is good enough to provide traffic stats for each port (e.g. via SNMP) you can measure things there and use one of the many network monitoring tools available or just write a simple script to poll the data at regular intervals, calculate some deltas and even do some math to aggregate them into one overall statistic of bandwidth usage.  If your switch doesn't allow for this then you'd have to do it and the other end of the wires, i.e. your hosts.

This can be simplified depending on what you actual goal is.  If all you want is to see who is hogging your uplink's bandwidth you can do it at the gateway.

Comment: So, you mean, that if I have one million of 1G connections to my `LAN` it will hande all of them? No collisions, no overload? This can't be true.

Suppose I want to measure how does transmission between node `A` (a camera) to node `B` (a storage computer) affect connections of node `C` with other nodes. Neither `C` connects to `A` or `B`, nor traffic between `A` and `B` goes throught the router.

Comment: If `A`, `B`, `C` etc are all on the same switch, whether `A-B` will affect `C-*` depends on the switch's capabilities (measured in packets per second, not necessarily bits, although both are obviously related). If `A-B` are on the same switch and `C-*` are on a another one, of course they won't have any effect. (Note: we're straying from the original question)

Comment: Suppose everybody are on one switch. How to measure the load? Isn't it possible to write a code which will listen packets in promiscuous mode and sum their size?

Comment: Switches aren't hubs, they are smarter (and thus more efficient). If a packet from the host on port 1 is meant for the host on port 2, it won't show up on any other port.

Comment: Suppose we are on bus. How to measure load?

Comment: If you mean on a hub, you probably can listen on promiscuous mode. But those measurements won't be of much use if you normally use a switch, since hubs are much less efficient. (Again, we are straying from the original question and this is becoming a chat, comments aren't meant for this. Please consider opening a new question).

Answer (score 0):

> How to measure entire! LAN load for example with ntopng?
> Is it possible to measure LAN load in the same way as it possible to measure CPU usage with top

You can measure the load an interface but you cannot measure the load for a whole LAN from one of its hosts.

Why? Because there is a lot of traffic you will never ever see, traffic not directed to you, or traffic belonging to other VLANs for example. Those will be filtered at the switch.

In order to see all traffic you would need to be the software running the switch (and then again, have all hosts connected to you) or turn the switch into a hub.

If you want to see the usage for a specific link out of the LAN, then you need that link to be one of your interfaces (you would then most likely be the router for the LAN). And then you have many solutions, some of them already mentioned in the other answers.